# Delonghi Dedica rubber wand is propelled into milk pitcher

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine, froth

I own a Delonghi Dedica EC685 and looking to get some proper microfoam for latte art, I removed the Panarello tube and tried to froth the milk using just the inner rubber tube.

Problem right now is that it works for a few seconds and then the rubber tube detaches itself from the pipe and it's propelled into my milk pitcher.

I did check the tube, it looks clean, nothing clogging it.

Any idea what can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

I think the panarello is keeping the inner rubber tube in place, so it's normal for the tube to pop off under pressure. You can hold the tube in place by using a cable tie as can be seen in this video: [Frothing milk for latte art with the De'Longhi Dedica EC685](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApDjtXaHa7U).

[image: cable tie]

However, that solution will make it difficult to remove the tube for cleaning. I suggest using a wire spring clip to hold the rubber tube into place, while still being easy to remove. For reference, I'm using a [Mikalor Double Wire Spring Hose Clip 12.9-13.6mm](https://www.advancedfluidsolutions.co.uk/mikalor-double-wire-spring-hose-clip-129---136mm-1637-p.asp). This is quite a tight fit and not so easy to place/remove, so you might want to use a slightly larger clip.

[image: wire spring clip]

Be careful not to use a spring clip that is too small so as not to damage the plastic over which the tube is slid.

Answer (score 1):

Open the steam valve after it's heated up to release the built-up pressure. Then use it for steaming to avoid the rubber tip from shooting off due to high sudden pressures.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but actually I am already doing it. The shooting  happens 10-15 seconds in the frothing process, and weirdly enough it happens in milk, soap water but not when trying with plain water.

Comment: This might mean that your boiler is generating pressure faster than it is being released. Or the wand is partly blocked which causes pressure build-up. When was the last time you descaled your machine? Still weird it's not happening in plain water though...

Comment: I've only had the machine for about 2 weeks and used it probably around 30-40 times so I haven't descaled it yet. I filter the water before pouring it in the tank, but the water is kinda bad around thsi parts, so I guess I could give descaling a try, see it it changes anything.

Comment: @maephisto If you've only had it for 2 weeks, it's unlikely that it's a descaling issue. It might be an issue if you had not been purging the steam wand after steaming which could have drawn in some residue milk and caused partial blockage. It's not immediately clear what's exactly wrong and it could equally be a fault with the machine causing a lot of pressure build up.

Answer (score 1):

The same question with answers is here: [Pannarello wand on Delonghi Dedica EC685 for latte art](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/pannarello-wand-on-delonghi-dedica-ec685-for-latte-art)

The possible solution is to enlarge a bit output hole on the rubber wand.

Comment: I've tried widening the hole with a smooth chopstick. To no avail.

I've tried widening it with a hot needle. The rubber seems to be of a good quality thickness. Still didn't give me a hole wide enough.

Any ideas on how to widen this hole?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue - saved my self the hassle and cut the tip of the frothier nozzle by half and it gave it a wider opening - this helps ease the tension and pressure when steam is released

Answer (score -1):

I use a spring type gas line clip that is. Works perfectly.

Comment: Your Answer is very terse.  Perhaps adding some details such as where you found the spring type gas line clip will clarify how it is attached, making it more useful to future Readers.