# Pannarello wand on Delonghi Dedica EC685 for latte art

Tags: milk, espresso

I've read online that removing the sleeve of the pannarello wand and just using the inner rubber as a wand can create better micro foam, I was excited to try as I couldn't get my EC685 wand to produce nice foam for latte art. I've read that you need to release the pressure (purge) first before removing the sleeve. So I did. It worked for 5 seconds (and I can see it works so much better than with the sleeve). However...5 seconds later, the rubber flew into my jug and milk splashed everywhere. Has anyone had similar issues? Is it just not possible to use the EC685 wand without the sleeve?

Comment: I tried exactly the same, with exactly the same results. And what's worse - since then I am struggling with frothing milk. I suspect the wand is stuck in hot milk mode and not creating foam as it should. I am thinking of having it checked. Really disappointed as I was quite proud of my improving latte art skills. :(

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same machine and the inner rubber wand is tightly attached. It doesn't come off even if I pull it firmly. If yours is falling off that easily it could be that either it is clogged (so the steam pressure is shooting it off), or it is lose (which you should be able to push it back in place) or it is defective (or missing a part).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this part (inner rubber wand, Delonghi uses it not only in the EC680, but in many other models as well) has too tiny hole (output). That's why it deattaches. TheThe possible solution is to make a hole a bit larger using hot idle or a bradawl.

Comment: This seems like the closest thing to a solution I've read. Have you or anyone here tried it yet? I'm experiencing the same 5 second mess with my rubber wand - it flies off and creates a macro-spillage. LOL

But has anyone tried the hole-widening trick? I'm wary to try it myself lest it cause the panarrello attachment to never work correctly once I do it.

Comment: farankoshan, here is a video in Russian, where a guy fixes similar problem on his Delonghi 510.55 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USAU0DzBGQ4 He use a lower tube part from his previous machine, however, but it's clearly visible the difference in the hole diameter on the "right" and on the "defected" inner rubber wand.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix is to just add a small cable tie to it, worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by sawing off part of the outer wand. Only the top ring needs to be put back. 
-Remove the entire tube, incl. top ring.
-takeout therubber inner tube and put the steel outer sleeve back on
-Pull down the steel outer sleeve
-saw through the junction between sleeve and ring
-file down rough edges
-reinstall rubber tybe and top ring
Check out the full how-to here, with some pointers to make it easier. https://youtu.be/emA5NpS8epc
Or my instagram under the same name.
Best,
Michel

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers, instead put the important parts in text here and use the link for further reference.

Comment: Consider it done